# Нахождение необходимой пары Python

Tags: python

Всем привет. Подскажите с задачкой.

Имеется список:

```
[(0, 0), (-5, 2), (2, -5), (4, 4), (2, -1)]
```

в котором лежат кортежи (можно заменить на списки, не важно) с координатами x и y.

Нужно вывести 2 пары x и y:
первая - левее всех на графике
вторая - выше всех.

Например:
из этого списка левее всех пара (-5, 2), а выше всех - (4, 4)

Как вообще можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lst = [(0, 0), (-5, 2), (2, -5), (4, 4), (2, -1)]
print(min(lst)) 
print(max(lst, key=lambda a: a[1]))
```

min и max сортируют в начале по первым элементам кортежа. если они одинаковые - то сравниваются вторые. Поэтому чтобы найти крайнюю левую точку, просто ищем min, найдется минимальный x(первый элемент), а чтобы найти самую верхнюю точку я использовал key и lambda функцию. lambda  берет кортеж и передает на сортировку только его второй элементы a[1], то есть сортировка идет по вторым элементам кортежа.

Comment: Можно 1 проходом minmax найти